# How do I use T-SQL's Case/When?

Tags: t-sql, case-when

I have a huge query which uses *case/when* often. Now I have this SQL here, which does not work.

```
 (select case when xyz.something = 1
 then
     'SOMETEXT'
 else
      (select case when xyz.somethingelse = 1)
      then
          'SOMEOTHERTEXT'
      end) 

      (select case when xyz.somethingelseagain = 2)
      then
          'SOMEOTHERTEXTGOESHERE'
      end)
 end) [ColumnName],
```

Whats causing trouble is `xyz.somethingelseagain = 2`, it says it could not bind that expression. xyz is some alias for a table which is joined further down in the query. Whats wrong here? Removing one of the 2 case/whens corrects that, but I need both of them, probably even more cases.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

```
SELECT
   CASE 
   WHEN xyz.something = 1 THEN 'SOMETEXT'
   WHEN xyz.somethingelse = 1 THEN 'SOMEOTHERTEXT'
   WHEN xyz.somethingelseagain = 2 THEN 'SOMEOTHERTEXTGOESHERE'
   ELSE 'SOMETHING UNKNOWN'
   END AS ColumnName;
```

Comment: Works, whats the difference? :)

Comment: Lets say I have some of the whens as duplicates, like this:

WHEN xyz.something = 1 and xyz.abc = 2 THEN 'SOMETEXT'
WHEN xyz.something = 1 and xyz.abc <> 2 THEN 'SOMEOTHERTEXT'

Can I somehow say that if the first when was set that the upcoming ones are skipped? Something which escapes the case/when?

Comment: The original query has multiple SELECT statements, so MS SQL server is expecting subqueries. It an easy mistake to make if you're used to some programming languages that use select and case rather than CASE and WHEN.

Answer (score 8):

As soon as a WHEN statement is true the break is implicit.

You will have to concider which WHEN Expression is the most likely to happen. If you put that WHEN at the end of a long list of WHEN statements, your sql is likely to be slower. So put it up front as the first.

More information here: [break in case statement in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153853/break-in-case-statement-in-t-sql)

Comment: This is true a lot of the time, but is not guaranteed: http://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @n int = 7,
    @m int = 3;

select 
    case 
        when @n = 1 then
            'SOMETEXT'
    else
        case 
            when @m = 1 then
                'SOMEOTHERTEXT'
            when @m = 2 then
                'SOMEOTHERTEXTGOESHERE'
        end
    end as col1
-- n=1 => returns SOMETEXT regardless of @m
-- n=2 and m=1 => returns SOMEOTHERTEXT
-- n=2 and m=2 => returns SOMEOTHERTEXTGOESHERE
-- n=2 and m>2 => returns null (no else defined for inner case)
```

Answer (score 1):

If logical test is against a single column then you could use something like

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
SELECT   ProductNumber, Category =  
      CASE ProductLine  
         WHEN 'R' THEN 'Road'  
         WHEN 'M' THEN 'Mountain'  
         WHEN 'T' THEN 'Touring'  
         WHEN 'S' THEN 'Other sale items'  
         ELSE 'Not for sale'  
      END,  
   Name  
FROM Production.Product  
ORDER BY ProductNumber;  
GO
```

More information - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017