# Case statement to add extra column with custom data

Tags: sql, case

Need some help with building a case statement. My information brought back is telemetry based and need to adjust where a solution name is "Excel" I need it to rename it to "Microsoft Excel" (just an example). The coloumn with the data is called "Solution name".

Something in the line of Where solution name is "excel" then "MS excel"

Any help will be useful, thanks

Code below

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("xx.xxx.xx.xx\Telemetry", "TELEMETRY"),
    dbo_Lookup_solutions = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="Lookup_solutions"]}[Data]
in
    dbo_Lookup_solutions
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use T-SQL's Case/When?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342319/how-do-i-use-t-sqls-case-when)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Case when solution like ‘%excel%’ then ‘msexcel’ else solution end`

Comment: Thanks mate - where in the entire code set would I add that?

Comment: Using it in Power BI. This is the standard returned code it gave me when I created the connection and view.

Comment: I’d create a view in the dataset using the case statement. Or if doing in power i this would be dax. Try https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/CASE-Statement-to-DAX/m-p/185578#M81585